# Inequalities regarding odd degree polynomial's coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials

Define an odd degree polynomial as a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$

where n is odd.

We all know odd degree polynomials have special characteristics which they don't share with even degree polynomials, here I propose four of them, which I think are true, but I'm unable to prove. My final goal is to prove something I already know, which is that all odd degree polynomials have at least one real root.

i) $\mid x \mid \gt 1 \implies \mid \frac{a_{n-1}}{x} + ... +\frac{a_1}{x^{n-1}} + \frac{a_0}{x^n} \mid \lt \frac{1}{\mid x \mid}(\mid a_{n-1} \mid + \mid a_{n-2} \mid) + ... + \mid a_1 \mid + \mid a_0 \mid$

ii) $\mid x \mid \gt \max\{ 1,2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mid a_i \mid \}\implies \mid \frac{a_{n-1}}{x} + ... +\frac{a_1}{x^{n-1}} + \frac{a_0}{x^n} \mid \lt \frac{1}{2}$

iii) $x_1 \gt \max\{ 1,2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mid a_i \mid \} \implies f(x_1) \gt 0$

iv) $x_2 \lt -\max\{ 1,2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mid a_i \mid \} \implies f(x_2) \lt 0$

Any help or proof is appreacieted.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the inequalities to prove the statement that ***an odd degree polynomial with real coefficients has at least one real root*** ?

This statement follows from the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) and from having/knowing these two limits:

$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty $
$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty $

So with some basic real analysis knowledge the statement can be proved easily.
Right?

Comment: Agreed that this is an application of the IVT (and the inequalities wouldn't avoid that). The question does also appear, somewhat indirectly and perhaps with more inequalities than necessary, to be attempting to quantify the positiivty/negativity consequences of those limits (and get bounds on a root) in explicit terms of the polynomial's coefficients. Which would require more than just knowing the limits.